# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

I am new to Meteor, I cloned the repo from Heroku in my locall machine and then replace the 4 folders( `cleint server imports public`) with my existing project. 
Then I run `meteor npm install` and then `npm install` and then `npm start`.
Project running smoothly, I tried Sign up the user, And it succeed but in login, It shows error like ->

```
(node:11590) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

And

```
(node:14263) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
```

I don't have any idea, where is this error coming from and even tried every link regarding the same issue but still nothing worked.

My login code ->

```
 Meteor.call('affiliateLogin',values, (err,res)=>{
              if(err){
                console.log(' in catch and err -------- ')
                console.log(err);
              }
              else{
                console.log(' in response - res.data --- ')
                console.log(res);
                this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
              }
            });
```

And my `affiliateLogin` method is ->

```
  affiliateLogin(values) {
    console.log(' these are the values--- ', values) // i am getting the values here.
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${baseURL}/rest-api/affiliateAuthenticate.php`,
      data: `userid=${values.email}&password=${values.password}&api_secret=secret`,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
      .then(res => { return res.data })
      .catch(err => { return err })
  }
```

My meteor version ->

```
 meteor --version
Meteor 1.8.1
```

And Node version ->

```
node --version
v10.15.3
```

Comment: The promise is rejected and the error is not handled properly. You can read on `Meteor.wrapAsync` as well as `Meteor.bindEnvironment` in the documentation for more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue while working with protractor, typescript in one of my project.
this was the issue I had :-

```
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at new Wait (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\utilities\Wait.ts:5:1)
at new SelectDropDown (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\utilities\SelectDropDown.ts:5:1)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:29:23)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
```

**Solution** Tech Stack which of my project:-

- Protractor
- Typescript
- Page Object Modal
- Cucumber
- Chai
- node
- npm
- VS Code (IDE)

https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/unhandled-rejection-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/